# Wordpress Query: Order by category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a page that displays *WooCommerce* products from the database.

Currently, these items are ordered by date, newest shown first.

These products belong to various categories. We would like to push all the products belonging to category 'hold' to the end of the list, whilst keeping the date ordering.

Currently, I can only hide the 'hold' category products from the listing by using the following code in my **functions.php** file.

```
$q->set( 'tax_query', array(
                    array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'hold' ), // Don't display 'hold' category products
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                    )
                )
            );
```

We attempted to tweak the code as follows to simply push the 'hold' products to the end of the list, but it did not work:

```
$q->set( 'tax_query', array(
                    array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'orderby' => 'product_cat',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'hold' )
                    )
                )
            );
```

Any ideas on how to make this custom sorting work?

Thanks in advance!
Nick

Comment: I think this is not possible via arguments. In any case you should have shown what you've tried so far (which is not stopping only because it does not work out of the box - even it might look hard fro you to go on). A universal answer might be: By writing the correct SQL query.

Comment: I also think this is not possible. At best you could maybe query all the products that are *not* in the product category and then merge that with a query of all products that *are* in the specific product category. I wouldn't know how to handle the pagination on that though.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That makes a lot of sense. Will try to tackle this problem in a different way.